# CountDownTimer recursion

Tags: android, recursion, countdowntimer

I have a game that needs to spawn creatures on certain periods of time and i did so by doing a CountDownTimer that calls itself when it's finished, like so:

```
private void startTimer(final long milliseconds){
  CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 0){
        public void onTick(long millisUntilDone){
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            /*when done, creates a new creature*/
            createCreature();
            startTimer(milliseconds-50); 
        }
    };
    counter.start();
}
```

But it just creates one creature, maybe 2 if i am lucky.
Can anyone tell me what did i do wrong, and how to correct it?

Comment: you do realise that you start your next timer 50 milliseconds faster then the one before? so if you would do a startTimer(150) I can imagine you only get 3 creatures

Comment: yes, i am aware of this issue, i will fix it later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to use intervals.

```
private void startTimer(final long milliseconds){
  CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 50){
    public void onTick(long millisUntilDone){
        createCreature();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        createCreature();
    }
  };
  counter.start();
}
```